# JQuery Autocomplete using Label and Value pairs

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to implement jquery autocomplete feature on my jsp page. Idea is that on load, a list will be populated by retrieving data from db table and return that list and use it as source.

Below is my Distributor Class, I would like to use distributorName as Label and distributorId as Value.

**Distributor Java Object Class**

```
public class DistributorObject {

    private BigInteger distributorId;
    private String distributorName;
    private String distributorNameUpper;

...Getters and Setters
```

Question is how do I correctly set those two values as label and value properties on a javascript variable?

**Current JSP Script**

```
$(function() {
    var availableTutorials = [];
    <c:forEach items="${allDistributorsList}" var="distributor" varStatus="status">
        var distrib = {label: ${distributor.distributorName}, value: ${distributor.distributorId}};
        availableTutorials.push(distrib);
    </c:forEach>
    $( "#automplete-1" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTutorials
    });
});
```

This particular piece of code is not working:

```
var distrib = {label: ${distributor.distributorName}, value: ${distributor.distributorId}};
```

But if I replace it with actual String values, it would work. Such as:

```
var distrib = {label: "zzzz", value: "1"};
```

Also when viewing the page source, I could see that ${distributor.distributorName} is populated correctly. So I am quite at a loss as to why I can't use it as property value.

Thanks,

Philip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your browser console you should see an error like `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`.

Looks like those are string values, so you will have to enclose them in `''` as below(If `distributorId` is a numeric value then there is no need to enclose it in `''` like a string literal).

```
var distrib = {
    label: '${distributor.distributorName}',
    value: '${distributor.distributorId}'
};
```